# Are all of the finalizers invoked during a garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

Let's say i'm trying to allocate 100 bytes, but since I don't have 100 bytes available in my GC heap, a garbage collection is triggered. Also, in my GC heap there's 100mb worth of unreachable objects. To my understanding, once the GC freed 100bytes, he could decide to stop the collection and continue the program's execution. So let's say the GC didn't freed 50mb worth of objects, that are equal to 100 different objects.

My question is this: does the GC invoke **all** of the finalizers? even though it isn't going to delete them? (in this case, the 100 unreachable objects that the GC decided not to delete).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that anything here could be an implementation detail, and it could be different between x86 / x64 / ia64, server vs workstation (very different GC profile), Mono vs MS .NET, OS version, .NET/CLI major version, .NET/CLI patch version, Compact Framework, Micro Framework, etc.

I don't think you should assume *any* specific behaviour, other than "objects with finalizers that are not in use will probably get finalized at some point, but even that isn't guaranteed".

Comment: +1. And yes, in other words, "you can't know and shouldn't really think about it".

Comment: I.e., "Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent."

Answer (score 1):

"once the GC freed 100bytes, he could decide to stop the collection" - no, the GC wouldn't stop collection. It will always collect generation 0. If that's not sufficient, go on with Gen1 and Gen2+LOB.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage-collection in .net has two aspects: finalization and destruction.  When an object that has a finalizer is created, it is added to a special list I'll call the "finalizable" list.  Each time the garbage-collector runs, it identifies objects which aren't reachable by anything, those which are reachable only from "finalizable" list or objects therein, and those which are reachable by something else without going through the "finalizable" list.  Objects which aren't reachable at all are destroyed.  Those which are only reachable from the "finalizable" list or objects therein are removed from that list and put into a "finalize-now" list.  Objects which are reachable by something other than the "finalizable" list survive the GC.  While the GC is sorting objects into those three categories, all code execution is stopped.  Once the GC is done, code execution resumes, and a special thread will start running the Finalize method of all objects in the "Finalize now" list.

Note that objects in the "finalize now" list, as well as any objects referenced thereby, will not be garbage-collected as long as they are in that list; they can only become eligible for garbage collection after their finalizer has run.  Once they are no longer in the "finalize now" list, they may again be eligible for collection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  The only time the finalizers are run is when the object is being destroyed.

Comment: "Are finalizers called even though [an object] has not been garbage collected?" - Clearly: no

Comment: Objects which are eligible for finalization are, by virtue of that eligibility, not eligible for destruction.  Once an object has been finalized, it will no longer be eligible for finalization; consequently, unless a strong reference to it was created during finalization (of itself or some other object) it will be eligible for destruction.

Answer (score 0):

The GC does multiple passes.  It looks for unreachable objects and when it finds them checks if they have a finalizer.  If there is a finalizer, then it puts them into a separate finalizer queue and if not, cleans them up.  So on first pass, it doesn't actually call any finalizers, it just organizes objects based on whether or not they have finalizers.

Comment: You've missed the point of my answer ... the question is whether the GC can decide to stop a collection once it dosen't need to free any more objects (so their finalizer won't be invoked even though "some collection" happened)